# Which animal comes next in the series?

Tags: word, pattern, sequence

This question was asked in [Hiqora iq-test](http://www.hiqora.com/round-2/).

> Which animal comes next in the series?
> Elk, Mink, Mouse, Gibbon, Panther....

Options:

1. Squirrel
2. Tortoise
3. Wildebeest
4. Platypus

What is the answer, and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> tortoise

Because...

> the name of each creature commences with the letter that come two letters in the alphabet after the last letter of the previous creature. Also the name of each creature contains one more letter than the previous creature.

Comment: Perfect reasoning, kudos :)

Answer (score 4):

Could be

> squirrel

because

> it has one more letter than the previous, and it's a placental mammal.

Comment: +1 as this is very close to the correct answer and is logical enough ( considering the class Mammal of animals). But the other one is marked as correct as this question was under IQ section and not under general intelligence where knowledge and trivia is checked.